# How to create a note that include the day automatically?

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I will like to  see the way to obtain  automatically the day in a note, to have a follow up,

```
// Add the date when you create a note

function Notes() 
{
   
  var app= SpreadsheetApp;
  var activeSheet = app.getActiveSpreadsheet().getActiveSheet(); // Returns the active shee
  var activeRange= activeSheet.getActiveRange() // Returns the active Range
  
  activeRange.setNote(Date());  // Set the date in the note


  
}
```

This code is working but I obtain this: Thu Oct 22 2020 08:28:09 GMT+0200 (Central European Summer Time)
and I will only like to obtain  22/10/2020 08:28:09  for example.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You just need to convert the date to the desired format `dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm:ss`. You can use [Utilities.formatDate()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/utilities/utilities) to achieve that:

```
function Notes() 
{
  var app= SpreadsheetApp;
  var activeSheet = app.getActiveSpreadsheet().getActiveSheet(); // Returns the active shee
  var activeRange= activeSheet.getActiveRange() // Returns the active Range
  var today = Utilities.formatDate(new Date(), app.getActive().getSpreadsheetTimeZone(), "dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm:ss");
  
  activeRange.setNote(today);  // Set the date in the note
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There are many ways to print a [Date](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date) in JS

```js
var d = new Date()

console.log(d.toString())
console.log(d.toISOString())
console.log(d.toDateString())
console.log(d.toGMTString())
console.log(d.toUTCString())
console.log(d.toTimeString())
console.log(d.toLocaleString())
console.log(d.toLocaleDateString())
console.log(d.toLocaleTimeString())
```

You can also build your own format using this getter methods:

```js
var d = new Date()

console.log(d.getFullYear() + "/" + (d.getMonth()+1) + "/" + d.getDate())
```

**Keep in mind that the date is a local object, and depends from the browser locale and timezone.**

Comment: But I would like to see that in the Note, not in the console log.  Thanks for the help!

Comment: just replace the Date() with the format you want in `activeRange.setNote(Date())`

Comment: I do it and it doesn´t work.  
 activeRange.setNote(d.getFullYear() + "/" + (d.getMonth()+1) + "/" + d.getDate()+ "TM")  
Thanks in advance